# change the position of the nstableview programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, view, tableview

I have a tableview present in my IB. I am trying to change the position of the table view present in IB in awakefromnib using the following code.

```
[[[_menuTableView superview] superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];
[[_menuTableView superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];

[_menuTableView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];
```

I have written these 3 lines since I have to change the position of all the views present(Scrollview,clipview and tableview.)

The problem is tableview position is not changed even after executing the above lines.
How to achieve this?

Code

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize searchField;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil!= self)
    {
        _arrayContents= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"as",@"sd",@"dfg",@"fh",@"sdf",@"ret",@"sdf",@"dsfxc",@"awert",@"xsdfcvg", nil];
        _searchedArrayContents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_arrayContents count]];

        _menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123",@"1231234",@"235435",@"5345345", nil];
    }
    return  self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
//    [_menuTableView setHidden:YES];
//    [[[_menuTableView superview] superview] setHidden:YES];

    [[[_menuTableView superview] superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 0, 234, 1000)];
    [[_menuTableView superview] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];

    [_menuTableView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 234, 1000)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    if (aTableView==_menuTableView)
    {
        return  [_menuArray count];
    }

    if ([[searchField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_tokenField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_textField stringValue] length]>0)
    { 
        return [_searchedArrayContents count];
    }
    if (aTableView==_tableView)
    {
        return [_arrayContents count];
    }
    return  0;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn         *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    if (aTableView==_menuTableView)
    {
        return  [_menuArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    }

    if ([[searchField stringValue] length]>0 || [[_tokenField stringValue] length]>0)
    {
        return [_searchedArrayContents objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    }

    if (aTableView==_tableView)
    {
        return [_arrayContents objectAtIndex:rowIndex] ;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: have you connected tableview reference(_menuTableView) in IB?

Comment: Yes. I have connected the reference. The data is being displayed as well. I need to move the table view based on certain condition

Comment: then move tableview according to your condition.

Comment: I need to move it dynamically (programmatically) based on certain condition. Is it possible to change the position dynamically?

Comment: I tried with the abouve code. But the tableview doesnot move at all. It stays in the same position. AM I missing something?

Comment: Please add some of your code.